# How do I Log the correct type of an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I have an `array` that looks like this:

```
NSArray* phoneDicts = [currentPerson objectForKey:@"phones"];
```

And to Log the result I use a loop like this:

```
for(id index in phoneDicts) {
        NSLog(@" phoneDicts:%@", index);
    }
```

But the only output I get is this:

```
2019-09-23 16:11:41.142931+0200 Mi[13183:468712] -[CurrentPerson phoneStatuses] line 315 $  phoneDicts:{
```

It ends with `{` and I'm not sure what that means.
I did a nil check to make sure it wasn't void of data. I also did a count on phoneDicts and it returned 4, so there is definitely data on the array.

I also tried:

```
NSLog(@" phoneDicts object for key: %@", [phoneDicts valueForKey:@"phones"]);
```

But this gave me similar results, this time ending with `(`:

```
2019-09-23 16:11:41.142609+0200 Mi[13183:468712] -[CurrentPerson phoneStatuses] line 313 $  phoneDicts object for key: (
```

So, what am I missing? New to objective-c, so I'm not sure if I'm logging the result the right way.

Comment: Looks to me like `currentPerson` is an `NSString`, possibly in JSON format.

Comment: This doesn't look like `NSLog` output. Where is "line 318" coming from? Perhaps you've aliased `NSLog` to something nonstandard (possibly something that doesn't handle newlines)? Typically the output would be something like `2019-09-23 09:24:23.651776-0400 test[87523:24793248] Hello, World!`

Comment: Fo me it's look's like that you have some parameters in log filter.

Comment: @RobNapier Sorry, I was just shortening it. I have updated now.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes, I filter the emoji to find it easier, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You have filtered the rest of the log message.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Holy cow, you are right! It must have removed the data from the log to because there was so much of it. Removing my search filter and just looking through my log I can now find all the data! Big thanks!!! Write a real response if you want me to accept the answer.